# Rotating an image if the height is larger than width?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to rotate an image if and only if, the aspect ratio of the image is > 1, else just print the original picture and afterwards use the data.

My problem is that *Mathematica* writes "expecting an image instead of null", because of the `If` statement.

Comment: I don't see any code you've written. In any event, what you can do is have the second argument of `ImageRotate[]` be a conditional.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one method you can try, although you don't specify exactly how you would like the image to be rotated - you can edit the `90 Degree` angle to your own requirements.

```
test = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], {256, 256}];
crop = ImageCrop[test, {128, 256}]
```

[image]

```
rotateImage = ImageRotate[#, If[ImageAspectRatio[#] > 1, 90 Degree, 0]] &;    
rotateImage[crop]
```

[image]

### Edit

A comment suggests a different order for the rotation function, which doesn't call `ImageRotate[]` unnecessarily, namely:

```
rotateImage2 = If[ImageAspectRatio@# > 1, ImageRotate[#, 90 Degree], #] &;
```

This avoids a  performance overhead if no rotation is required, since `image` is faster than `ImageRotate[image, 0 Degree]`.

Comment: Why not use `ImageAspectRatio[]`?

Comment: @J.M. because I forgot about that one? Now changed :-)

Comment: …upvoted now. :)

Comment: I would do it the other way round to prevent an unnecessary call to `ImageRotate` if no rotation is needed: `rotateImage = If[ImageAspectRatio@#>1,ImageRotate[#,90 Degree],#]&` as `If` has the `HoldRest` attribute.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP good point, I've added it in (though for reference there appears to be next-to-no performance difference between the two approaches).

Comment: Can't test that, I'm afraid, our license server suddenly died :( I do recall, that image-manipulating functions tend to be slow.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, I do indeed see your point! Though timings (updated) tell a different story.

Comment: The test rotates by 90 for both functions, no?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yes both functions rotate

Comment: Somehow, I thought the function was sufficiently smart not to do anything if the rotation angle was zero.

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought needed to be tested: is `ImageRotate[image, 0 Degree]` as fast as simply `image`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP sorry, yes I see your point, `image` is indeed faster than rotating by 0 degrees!

Comment: I'm new to mathematica, but i've tried to adjust the code to the "test" and "crop"   
rotate3 = 
 If[ImageAspectRatio[crop] > 1.0, Rotate[crop, 90 Degree], 
  Print[crop]]
But then the problem:
ImageData[rotate3] - Expecting an image or graphics instead of (the rotated image). Sorry for the lack of information. Even if I convert the image to grayscale, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @GitteSigvertNielsen Why are you using a `Print[]` statement?

Comment: It was something, we learned in class. I study robotics at University of Southern Denmark